# Appending 2D lists

Tags: python

I want to create a 2-dimensional list `F`, by repeatedly appending other 2-dimensional lists to `F`. For example, suppose that I have the following lists `x` and `y`:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
y = [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Then I want to append `x` to an empty matrix, and then append `y` to that matrix, for form `F`:

```
>>> F
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

However, if I try the following:

```
F = [[]]
F.append(x)
F.append(y)
```

Then I get the output:

```
>>> F
[[], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]
```

Which is not what I want. What is the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
>>> F = []
>>> F.extend(x)
>>> F.extend(y)
>>> F
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: any changes to F will also affect x  and y

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want changes in x or y to effect F or vice versa you should make a `deepcopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy

F = [deepcopy(x),deepcopy(y)]
```

Comment: Or just do `F.extend(x[:])` etc. But I guess `deepcopy()` is a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to append the *elements* of x and y to F, rather than x and y themselves. Use:

```
F = x + y
```

Or

```
F = []
F += x
F += y
```